# How get to the list until the end of the sequence?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I use php file_get_content of this,

how to get all list of link url so that the final sequence, how the sample coding?

```
<td class="pl-video-title">
<a class="pl-video-title-link yt-uix-tile-link yt-uix-sessionlink  spf-link " dir="ltr" href="/watch?v=wU8SbHTVavA&amp;list=PLFgquLnL59alPugCjEbuH3CAOkfY4PSWU&amp;index=40" data-sessionlink="ei=6KiqV5v_DtW0oAOc_LbIBQ&amp;feature=plpp_video&amp;ved=CDIQxjQYJyITCJuTx_78tc4CFVUaaAodHL4NWSj6LA">
  Dave Matthews Band - American Baby
</a>  </td>
```

i must click "load more"  on youtube list to display of more than 100 list URL https://s10.postimg.org/uncq8an8p/2016_08_10_092631.png ( sory i cant embed img because reputation is less than 10 )

please your help

Comment: please explain this "how to get the all list so that the final sequence, how the sample code themselves?"

Comment: @coder hy Mr.Coder, i update my post please your help :D

Comment: no one respon again :(